# How can I save an image with Image.thumbnail using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Basically, I copied and paste a script, and merged it with other script, and now the script doesn't work, it says an error "NoneType object has no attribute save"[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3IOj.png)
And here's the script:
`   from PIL import Image
import PIL
import os
from glob import glob

```
imgs = [y for x in os.walk(".") for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.png'))]

size = 32, 32
lastdir = None
for file in imgs:
    img = Image.open(file)
    img = img.thumbnail(size, resample=PIL.Image.NEAREST)
    file = file.replace('img', 'icon', 1)
    dir = os.path.dirname(file)
    try:
        os.makedirs(dir)
    except:
        pass
    if dir!=lastdir:
        print(dir)
    lastdir = dir
    img.save(file + ".png", "PNG")`
```

Resize various images on various directories and save them, but the images are not saving.

Answer (score 0):

The `thumbnail()` method modifies its object rather than returning a new one. So, this line:

```
img = img.thumbnail(size, resample=PIL.Image.NEAREST)
```

should be:

```
img.thumbnail(size, resample=PIL.Image.NEAREST)
```